# Unable to insert id column of table in order using sequence.nextvalue

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, sequence

I am using Oracle as DB and I have two tables.

```
TableOne-->tableOneId(Primary key)

TableTwo-->tableTwoId(Primary key),tableOneId(Foreign Key),City
```

Now there are many records in TableOne and for each record in table one I am trying to insert 5 cities in table 2 using below query.

```
insert into tableTwo (tableTwoId,tableOneId,City)
select TableTwo_SEQ.nextval,tableOneId,City from TableOne,(select 'city1' City from dual union select 'city2' City from dual
union select 'city3' City from dual union select 'city4' City from dual union select 'city5' City from dual)
```

But the cities insertd for each tableOneId does not have ordered table two.
e.g

```
SQL: select * from TableTwo where tableOneId='1022' order by tableTwoId

----------------------------------------
tableTwoId    tableOneId     City
----------------------------------------
10336          1022          City five

10889          1022          City four

11442          1022          City one

11995          1022          City three

12548          1022          City two
```

How can I insert the tableTwoId in order with cities.

Comment: Post the DDL and INSERTs for the tables involved. Also, your insert select is doing a **Cartesian join**, thus `553` iterations.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SELECT TableTwo_SEQ.nextval,
>   tableOneId,
>   City
> FROM TableOne,
>   (SELECT 'city1' City FROM dual
>   UNION
>   SELECT 'city2' City FROM dual
>   UNION
>   SELECT 'city3' City FROM dual
>   UNION
>   SELECT 'city4' City FROM dual
>   UNION
>   SELECT 'city5' City FROM dual
>   )
> ```

You are doing a **CARTESIAN JOIN** and thus for each row in `TableOne` there is a join with 5 rows in the union all. Therefore, you see a difference of `553` between each sequence number. It means the cartesian product resulted in 553 rows.

You must either specify a key to join the table and the in-line view or do it in 5 separate inserts.

For example,

```
INSERT INTO tableTwo
  (tableTwoId,tableOneId,City
  )
SELECT TableTwo_SEQ.nextval,
  tableOneId,
  'city1'
FROM TableOne;

INSERT INTO tableTwo
  (tableTwoId,tableOneId,City
  )
SELECT TableTwo_SEQ.nextval,
  tableOneId,
  'city2'
FROM TableOne;

INSERT INTO tableTwo
  (tableTwoId,tableOneId,City
  )
SELECT TableTwo_SEQ.nextval,
  tableOneId,
  'city3'
FROM TableOne;

INSERT INTO tableTwo
  (tableTwoId,tableOneId,City
  )
SELECT TableTwo_SEQ.nextval,
  tableOneId,
  'city4'
FROM TableOne;

INSERT INTO tableTwo
  (tableTwoId,tableOneId,City
  )
SELECT TableTwo_SEQ.nextval,
  tableOneId,
  'city5'
FROM TableOne;
```

This will insert the 5 cities for each tableOneId.

Comment: Hi Lalit,I am getting same result with seprate insert also.Still I am getting difference of 553 rows.

Comment: Then post the create table and insert statements to build a test case

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using below query:

```
INSERT INTO tableTwo 
SELECT TableTwo_SEQ.nextval,
    tableOneId,
    City
  FROM
    (SELECT tableOneId,
      City
    FROM TableOne,
      (SELECT 'city1' City FROM Dual
      UNION
      SELECT 'city1' City FROM Dual
      UNION
      SELECT 'city1' City FROM Dual
      UNION
      SELECT 'city1' City FROM Dual
      UNION
      SELECT 'city1' City FROM Dual
      ) elg
    ORDER BY 1,
      2
    );
```